# Symfony2 image asset in CSS background

Tags: css, image, symfony, assets

I have a problem with an image asset in symfony2, which I defined as a background in the css file. But, The image is always not found by the browser.

Here's my stylesheets block from the base layout :

```
 {% stylesheets '@FsHomeBundle/Resources/public/css/common.css'
                       '@FsHomeBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' filter="cssrewrite"  %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

And here's my css:

```
.header{
    background-image:url('../images/hdbg.png');
}
```

The image is located in `src/Fs/HomeBundle/Resources/public/images/hdbg.png`

**Note:** I tested also without `cssrewrite` filter , and it didn't work either, I tested changing the url as well.

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

**Edit** Note also that I'm working in /app_dev.php , and I do a assets:install and assetic:dump and also cache:clear every time I make a test.

Comment: can you confirm the image is installed in web and is accessible in the browser?

Comment: I checked these two URLS : `app_dev.php/bundles/fshome/images/hdbg.png` and `app_dev.php/web/bundles/fshome/images/hdbg.png`...

All of theme show a ResourceNotFoundException... 

But the image is located in `/web/bundles/fshome/images/hdbg.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing your assets (I'd recommend using symlink):

```
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

You should see a message like:

```
…
Installing assets for Fs\HomeBundle into web/bundles/fshome
…
```

Take note of the path like `web/bundles/fshome` path and use that instead of the `@Bundle` syntax:

```
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/fshome/css/common.css'
    'bundles/fshome/css/main.css'
     filter="cssrewrite"
 %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Now `cssrewrite` should write the correct path.

This is a known limitation of `cssrewrite`, from [github issues](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/512#issuecomment-26315257):

> the cssrewrite filter does not work with the @bundle notation for
>   stylesheets (because it will rewrite the path without taking into
>   account that images will be moved from the bundle to the web folder

Comment: That's great , it works ...thank you so much +1 and Best answer, It took me sometime before I figure out that I need to execute the console as an administrator. The problem is solved.

Comment: I don't know what this symlink is for... I'm going to check it out in Docs and read about it.

Comment: you should read up about it but in short `--symlink` will save you trips to the command line

Answer (score 2):

Try running "app/console assets:install web".

Comment: I see that the generated css file used is (css/56c0165_main_2.css), and the image is located in (web/bundles/fshome/images/hdbg.png)... one would expect that background-image:url('../images/hdbg.png') doesn't work.

And yes, I tried "app/console assets:install web" and it didn't work